# Delete contents in a range for specific condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get my VBA to select values that are "0" in my table and clear the contents of that cell.

So far I have been able to get look up the table column I want to see.

```
Sheets("formulas").Select
Range("machine_schedule[days ]").Select

If the days are 0 Then  ' <---- this is where I am having trouble.
    cell.Clear
End If
```

Comment: You may want to include one of your failed attempts. Please see [ask] and [reprex] and maybe take the [tour] as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable to avoid any kind of `.Select` when working with VBA. So the followinfg two lines are not needed (you can provide references without `.Select`).

```
Sheets("formulas").Select
Range("machine_schedule[days ]").Select
```

The following script checks every cell one by one in the provided range. If a zero is found, the cell is cleared. `.Clear` not only deletes the contents, it clears format too. If could use `.ClearContents` to only clear the contents.

```
Sub clear_zero()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheets("formulas").Range("machine_schedule[days ]")
  If cell.Value = 0 Then
    cell.Clear
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to clear the 0 values from the cells you could try this.

```
Sub ClearZeroes()
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim idx As Long

    With Sheets("formulas").Range("machine_schedule[days ]")
        arrData = .Value
        For idx = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If arrData(idx, 1) = 0 Then
                arrData(idxrow, 1) = ""
            End If
        Next idx
        .Value = arrData
    End With

End Sub
```